# Worksheet Change event not copying and pasting data

Tags: excel, vba

My present code is below.

I have two sheets in a workbook.

1.) Sheet Named - Data and Pasted

2.) Data Sheet is protected. Columns J to O are unprotected, Starting from cell J3:O1000. Rows 1 and 2 are reserved for headers.

3.) The range J:O automatically sorts with the help of the below code whenever there is **YES** in column N , while No will always be after YES, in the end blanks.

4.) This is working but it is not copying and pasting as values of those rows from J:O where it shows YES in column N

I can't understand why it is not working. TIA

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PastedSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim destinationRow As Long
    Dim isDataSheetUnprotected As Boolean
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set PastedSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pasted")
    
    Set KeyCells = Range("N3:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
        lastRow = DataSheet.Cells(DataSheet.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
        
        isDataSheetUnprotected = False
        If DataSheet.ProtectContents Then
            DataSheet.Unprotect Password:="Mama, I'm Coming Home"
            isDataSheetUnprotected = True
        End If
        
        DataSheet.Range("J3:O" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=DataSheet.Range("N3:N" & lastRow), _
            Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
        
If UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then
    MsgBox "Copying data for row " & Target.Row
    destinationRow = PastedSheet.Cells(PastedSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    MsgBox "Destination row in Pasted sheet: " & destinationRow
    Set sourceRange = DataSheet.Range("J" & Target.Row & ":K" & Target.Row)
    sourceRange.Copy
    DataSheet.Range("A" & destinationRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    MsgBox "Data copied and pasted"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
        
        If isDataSheetUnprotected Then
            DataSheet.Protect Password:="Mama, I'm Coming Home"
        End If
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you confirm this code is in the code-behind for Sheet "Data"? Also, as it stands, the code to do the copy/paste will only trigger when the change (ie that triggers `Worksheet_Change`) is changing a cell in column N (row 3 down) to "YES" (or "yes" etc) ... is that the intention?

Comment: The code to do the copy/paste will only trigger when you change a cell in column N from row 3 down and at or above the lowest already-not-blank cell and if you change it to "YES" (any case)  ... try change a "NO" cell in column N to "YES". Your code also sets `Application.EnableEvents` to False so if it ever errors (and so `Application.EnableEvents` is never set back to True) then the `Worksheet_Change` event code will never run at all. Try putting a `Debug.Print Now` line as the first line and see if anything appears in the Immediate window.

Comment: Close Excel (completely ... not just close the workbook) and re-open it and test again

Comment: Have you used the debugger to check what is going on?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `Application.EnableEvents = False` line then step through

Comment: the "not working anymore" is because of the `Application.EnableEvents = False` someone pointed out earlier. In the immediate window, type `Application.EnableEvents=True`. I don't see any reason why you would want to disable events anyways, I would suggest deleting that.

Comment: Please,  make a Sub with  a single code line: `Application.EnableEvents = True` and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pasting the data on the data sheet instead of on the pasted sheet. I've changed the line as needed:

```
If UCase(Target.Value) = "YES" Then
    MsgBox "Copying data for row " & Target.Row
    destinationRow = PastedSheet.Cells(PastedSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    MsgBox "Destination row in Pasted sheet: " & destinationRow
    Set sourceRange = DataSheet.Range("J" & Target.Row & ":K" & Target.Row)
    sourceRange.Copy
    PastedSheet.Range("A" & destinationRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'changed this line
    MsgBox "Data copied and pasted"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
```

Comment: It pasted the row from cell N6 onwards while the rows from N3 to N5 didnt. when i clean all the column N it gives me an error do you like to see the excel

Comment: Okay but the copy and paste problem in your question is solved. Next problem N3-N5 must be something else, likely related to your data, like if you have any blank cells it won't work properly. Next problem of clearing column N all at once gives you an error because your `Target` is now more than 1 cell, so `Target.Value` is not valid. You can either add a test to the macro to count the number of cells in `Target` or make sure you only change 1 cell at a time.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Copy Flagged Rows and Sort

**Before**

[image]

**After (copying `Q3:Q12` to `N3:N12`)**

[image]

**The Code**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_SORT_COLUMNS As String = "J:O" ' has to be contiguous
    Const SRC_COPY_COLUMNS As String = "J:K" ' has to be contiguous
    Const SRC_LAST_ROW_COLUMN As String = "J"
    Const SRC_FLAG_COLUMN As String = "N"
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW As Long = 3
    Const SRC_MAX_ROW As Long = 1000
    Const SRC_FLAG_STRING As String = "Yes" ' has to be a string
    Const SRC_PASSWORD As String = "Mama, I'm Coming Home"
    
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Pasted"
    Const DST_LAST_ROW_COLUMN As String = "A"
    
    ' Source
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    ' Since the code is in the sheet module, it's name is irrelevant.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Me ' or just use 'Me' instead of 'sws'
    ' The following will just make the code fail if you decide to rename.
    'Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    ' If you would like to put this code in a separate procedure,
    ' e.g. 'Sub BackupYeses(ByVal Target As Range)', you would have to use:
    'Set sws = Target.Worksheet ' or 'Set sws = Target.Parent'
    ' Then you would call it with 'BackupYeses Target' from this procedure.
    
    ' Reference the single-column 'flag' range.
    Dim sfrg As Range
    With sws.Columns(SRC_LAST_ROW_COLUMN)
        Dim slcell As Range: Set slcell = .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        If slcell.Row < SRC_FIRST_ROW Then Exit Sub ' no data
        If slcell.Row > SRC_MAX_ROW Then
            MsgBox "There is a limitation of " & SRC_MAX_ROW & " rows!", _
                vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim sfcell As Range: Set sfcell = .Cells(SRC_FIRST_ROW)
        Set sfrg = sws.Range(sfcell, slcell).EntireRow.Columns(SRC_FLAG_COLUMN)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the changed cells of the 'flag' range.
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(sfrg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
    ' Reference the (entire) 'copy' columns.
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = sws.Columns(SRC_COPY_COLUMNS)
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = scrg.Columns.Count
        
    ' Destination
    
    ' Reference the source sheet's workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = sws.Parent
    ' The following instead is perfectly fine:
    'Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' or just use 'ThisWorkbook' instead of 'wb'
        
    ' Reference the destination worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
        
    ' Reference the first destination single-row range.
    Dim drrg As Range
    With dws.Columns(DST_LAST_ROW_COLUMN)
        Set drrg = .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, scCount)
    End With
        
    ' Copy the flagged rows to the destination worksheet.
    
    Dim icell As Range, iStr As String
    
    For Each icell In irg.Cells
        iStr = CStr(icell.Value)
        If StrComp(iStr, SRC_FLAG_STRING, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            drrg.Value = scrg.Rows(icell.Row).Value
            Set drrg = drrg.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next icell
    
    ' Sort descending so the 'Yes'-es land above the 'No'-s.
    
    Dim IsUnprotected As Boolean ' already means 'IsUnprotected = False'
        
    If sws.ProtectContents Then
        sws.Unprotect Password:=SRC_PASSWORD
        IsUnprotected = True
    End If
'
    sfrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_SORT_COLUMNS).Sort _
        Key1:=sfrg, Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
    
    If IsUnprotected Then
        sws.Protect Password:=SRC_PASSWORD
    End If

    ' If you protect in the following way, ...
    'sws.Protect Password:=SRC_PASSWORD, AllowSorting:=True
    ' ... you don't need to unprotect anymore and you don't need to concern
    ' yourself with the 1000 rows issue.

End Sub
```